# Программная установка цвета на кнопку

Tags: java, android

Приложение падает когда пытаюсь программно установить цвет фона кнопки. Кнопку инициализировал в Java, всё связал. Ума не приложу, что не так. Пример того как я пытаюсь поставить фон:

```
q = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q);
q.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("@color/green"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));